# Searching using Scanner class in Java lang

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i want to search number in a text file and find its line(like index) and returns it.numbers are written line by line to the file.my method:

```
static int Src(int num)  
{
    int c=0;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(f); 
    while(s.hasNextInt())
     {
        c++;
        int l=s.nextInt();
        if(l==k)
          return c;
     }   
     return -1;
    }
```

but nothing happens.any tips?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? You get -1?

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happens'?  Nothing at all?  Errors?  Always `-1`?

Comment: returns anything with no errors.

Comment: @cane, `returns anything` doesn't answer our question clearly.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: like i said,on output screen nothing appears.nothing returns.

Comment: @cane, you aren't telling the method to output anything, so nothing should be printed.  You need to run `System.out.prinltn(Search(number))` in order to see output.

Comment: What is the format of the input file? Just longs? Just one long per line? I corrected my answer meanwhile - your `break` is misleading, and hit, if the return before isn't hit.

Comment: yes long numbers line by line as i mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see a `System.out.println();` anywhere to be found!

Comment: also method names should be `lowerCamelCase` in Java this isn't C#!

Comment: Editing the error in the question away is pretty senseless. You should only edit your post without changing the sense.

Answer (score 1):

What is the content of the file? Just longs? How is it delimited from the next long?

You don't count lines, but longs. And you always break, because your indentation is wrong. What you could do, is:

```
static int search (long k) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int c = 0;
    Scanner s=new Scanner (f); //f is a file predefined
    while (s.hasNextLong ())
    {
        c++;
        long l = s.nextLong ();
        if (l == k) 
        {
            return c; 
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you remove the `break` (you don't need a break after a return - it isn't reachable), you count the longs, so if you have one long per line, it would work. If you have something else, like "abc" between your longs, it will not work. A LineNumberReader with pattern matching ".*" + yourLong + ".*" would be more easy to use, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your test file and test case? It looks like it should work as is.

Some tips:

- Make sure the numbers in your file are actually `long`s. Remember that `long`s have a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1.
- Make sure you're reading from the correct file
- Make sure that f is a `File` and not a `String`
- Make sure that the file contains **only** `long`s. If it contains anything else, the `hasNextLong()` will return false prior to that token.

To debug:

- add a `System.out.println(l);` to check to see if you're reading in the correct numbers

Other tips:

- your method name should use internal capitalization (so it should be called `search()`)
- you do not need a `break` after your return